# How do I merge and filter dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to merge the `d` and `ann` dataframes but only keep the `FID` and `IID` from `d` dataframe and also the `Profile` from `ann` dataframe. I only want `BP` and `Unaffected control` profiles. I also want to change the `Profile` column name to `Phenotype`.

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
pheno <- d %>% merge(ann %>% filter(Profile=="BP"|Profile=="Unaffected control"), by=c("FID"="Database_ID"))
colnames(pheno)[Profile] <- "Phenotype"
```

| FID | IID | Phenotype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AC13 | 1 | BP |
| AC14 | 1 | BP |
| AC15 | 1 | Unaffected control |

`d` dataframe

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(FID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13", "AC14", 
"AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21", "AC22", 
"AC23", "AC24", "AC25", "AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2", "AC30", 
"AC31", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37", "AC38", 
"AC39", "AC3", "AC40", "AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45", "AC46", 
"AC47", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53", "AC54", 
"AC55", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61", "AC62", 
"AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6", "AC70", 
"AC71", "AC72", "AC73", "AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77", "AC78", 
"AC79", "AC7", "AC80", "AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84", "AC86", 
"AC87", "AC88", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92", "AC9", 
"AC100", "AC101", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104", "AC105", "AC16", 
"AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", "AC96", "AC97", "AC99", "DE10", 
"DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE16", "DE17", "DE18", "DE19", 
"DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE25", "DE26", "DE27", 
"DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", "DE36", "DE37", "DE38", "DE39", 
"DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", "DE44", "DE45", "DE46", "DE47", 
"DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE53", "DE54", 
"DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", "DE59", "DE60", "DE7", "DE9", 
"DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", "DE5"), IID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), SOL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), C1 = c(-0.00385609, 0.0101138, -0.0146168, -0.0218236, -0.0134745, 
-0.017089, 0.0152448, 0.0134359, 0.00540102, -0.0125389, 0.00463956, 
-0.00416079, -0.000325898, 0.0132781, 0.0130666, 0.00718399, 
-0.0051912, -0.0227934, 0.0364974, -0.0180301, -0.0226556, -0.00585266, 
0.0258924, -0.00994298, -0.00380612, 0.0187883, 0.0103367, 0.00747272, 
0.0191431, -0.00501846, -0.00118336, 0.0361201, 0.00830498, 0.00380194, 
0.00667686, -0.000441697, -0.00170991, -0.0281008, -0.00424591, 
0.0213412, 0.00261405, 0.016154, 0.0098956, 0.0141544, 0.0367203, 
0.0144693, 0.0256731, -0.00218851, 0.0204603, -0.000603019, -0.00504176, 
-0.00917368, 0.00237875, 0.0175946, 0.0188388, 0.0368965, -0.00408476, 
0.00871812, -0.00851917, 0.0252035, -0.00915532, 0.0223745, 0.016866, 
0.026825, 0.0366276, 0.0540474, 0.0386237, 0.0029996, 0.0207176, 
0.0177353, -0.0066377, 0.0343811, 0.0282509, 0.00526683, 0.0459516, 
0.00976286, 0.0259005, -0.00104822, -0.012696, 0.0134071, 0.0231658, 
0.00359455, 0.0194968, -0.000936478, -0.0029218, -0.0058512, 
-0.000837274, -0.0129465, -0.0102079, -0.00559039, 0.0118966, 
0.00147658, 0.0120396, -0.0104779, -0.0315149, -0.0115454, -0.0122457, 
-6.72242e-05, 0.00370599, -0.0164126, -0.0107853, -0.0271741, 
-0.0212005, -0.0445118, -0.0387773, -0.025109, -0.0321735, -0.0398603, 
-0.0266408, -0.0260984, -0.0296337, -0.0185381, -0.0403944, 0.0197937, 
-0.0176322, -0.013238, -0.0071666, -7.27277e-05, 0.00397489, 
0.0335056, -0.00604706, -0.00926438, 0.00706601, -0.0156982, 
-0.0275085, -0.00864179, -0.0247967, -0.030564, -0.00767327, 
-0.0235161, 0.00649758, -0.0329062, -0.0016138, -0.00701695, 
0.00819454, 0.0100377, 0.0250199, -0.0493141, -0.0216641, -0.0244709, 
-0.00466616, 0.016751, -0.0191688, -0.00492488, -0.0162364, -0.0167085, 
-0.0113427, 0.000422333, 0.030274, 0.0317995, 0.00237194, -0.00693838, 
-0.0100835), C2 = c(0.000865365, -0.001752, 0.0189917, -0.023343, 
-0.0340531, -0.0258976, -0.00794043, 0.0173163, 0.00639341, -0.0343077, 
0.01083, -0.0402179, 0.0158751, -0.00262893, -0.0216757, -0.00261259, 
-0.00542089, -0.00515714, 0.0105216, -0.0193606, 0.00692795, 
-0.0117295, -0.0235627, -0.00850041, -0.0156109, -0.00871875, 
-0.0163218, 0.0227143, -0.0161961, -0.0176719, -0.0070994, 0.0262932, 
0.00164033, -0.00969917, -0.0197631, -0.0154387, -0.0194608, 
0.00442207, -0.0234804, 0.00822342, -0.00657274, -0.0092332, 
0.0130892, -0.0345162, -0.0114187, -0.0129497, -0.00306092, 0.0417858, 
0.0262002, -0.0188849, -0.0184154, -0.0109956, -0.0151195, -0.00414531, 
0.010064, 0.0308816, -0.0153337, 0.0157867, -0.0289866, -0.0106713, 
0.000112714, -0.00152177, 0.0184509, 0.0112357, 0.00097954, 0.032083, 
0.0190258, -0.0371498, -0.0307498, -0.00947645, -0.00198995, 
0.015845, -0.0240248, -0.0122369, -0.00107049, -0.0144661, 0.0207883, 
-0.0418619, -0.0123712, -0.0212721, -0.00667244, -0.028512, -0.00522357, 
-0.018842, -0.0123026, -0.00511655, 0.0188473, 0.00739189, 0.0321578, 
-0.015449, 0.0214631, -0.00995001, -0.00144645, 0.00934907, 0.0344757, 
-0.0220224, 0.0121403, -0.00615057, -0.0208969, 0.0313899, -0.0251011, 
0.011635, 0.00536455, 0.0233033, -0.0019204, 0.0273593, 0.00844028, 
0.00181444, 0.02824, 0.0255231, 0.00266055, -0.00850383, -0.0129938, 
0.0268634, 0.0195986, 0.0320615, -0.0026514, 0.0127147, 0.014279, 
0.0553434, -0.020963, 0.00629119, -0.0244099, -0.0080923, 0.0173508, 
0.0485753, -0.00666049, 0.0501603, 0.0029162, 0.0267363, 0.0066606, 
0.00857736, 0.0172693, -0.00827586, -0.0117478, -0.00336638, 
0.00954265, -0.00889617, 0.00290055, 0.0229832, 0.0504569, 0.025979, 
-0.00795356, -0.0135421, -0.00359528, 0.0150037, -0.0105817, 
0.0167827, 0.0110882, 0.00200862, -0.00597284, -0.0188371, -0.00827599
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -153L))
```

The `Database_ID` and `Profile` columns in the `ann` dataframe (there are other columns in the `ann` dataframe...refer to below)

```
> dput(ann[c("Database_ID","Profile")])
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15", "AC17", "AC18", "AC19", "AC1", "AC20", "AC21",
"AC22", "AC23", "AC24", "AC25", "AC26", "AC27", "AC29", "AC2",
"AC30", "AC31", "AC32", "AC33", "AC34", "AC35", "AC36", "AC37",
"AC38", "AC39", "AC3", "AC40", "AC41", "AC42", "AC43", "AC45",
"AC46", "AC47", "AC48", "AC49", "AC50", "AC51", "AC52", "AC53",
"AC54", "AC55", "AC56", "AC57", "AC58", "AC5", "AC60", "AC61",
"AC62", "AC63", "AC64", "AC65", "AC66", "AC67", "AC69", "AC6",
"AC70", "AC71", "AC72", "AC73", "AC74", "AC75", "AC76", "AC77",
"AC78", "AC79", "AC7", "AC80", "AC81", "AC82", "AC83", "AC84",
"AC86", "AC87", "AC88", "AC89", "AC8", "AC90", "AC91", "AC92",
"AC9", "AC100", "AC101", "AC102", "AC103", "AC104", "AC105",
"AC16", "AC68", "AC93", "AC94", "AC95", "AC96", "AC97", "AC99",
"DE10", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE16", "DE17", "DE18",
"DE19", "DE1", "DE20", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE25", "DE26",
"DE27", "DE2", "DE33", "DE34", "DE35", "DE36", "DE37", "DE38",
"DE39", "DE3", "DE40", "DE41", "DE42", "DE44", "DE45", "DE46",
"DE47", "DE48", "DE49", "DE4", "DE50", "DE51", "DE52", "DE53",
"DE54", "DE55", "DE56", "DE57", "DE58", "DE59", "DE60", "DE7",
"DE9", "DE29", "DE30", "DE32", "DE43", "DE5"), Profile = c("Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "BP", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "Unaffected control", "BP", "Unaffected control", "BP",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.",
"Schiz.", "Schiz.", "BP", "Unaffected control", "Unaffected control",
"Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Dep.", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "BP",
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"Unaffected control", "Unaffected control", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.",
"Dep.", "BP", "Dep.", "BP", "Schiz.", "Unaffected control", "Dep.",
"BP", "Schiz.", "Dep.", "Dep.", "BP", "BP", "Schiz.")), row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46",
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57",
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68",
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79",
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90",
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109",
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118",
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127",
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136",
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145",
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153"), class = "data.frame")
```

There are other columns in `ann`, which I don't need.

```
> dput(head(ann))
structure(list(Database_ID = c("AC10", "AC11", "AC12", "AC13",
"AC14", "AC15"), Collection_type = c("Array", "Array", "Array",
"Array", "Array", "Array"), Age = c(40L, 51L, 19L, 49L, 48L,
44L), Round_Age = c(40L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 50L, 45L), sex = c("M",
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), race = c("White", "White", "White",
"White", "White", "White"), Profile = c("Schiz.", "Schiz.", "Schiz.",
"BP", "BP", "Unaffected control"), DSM_IV = c(295.9, 295.9, 295.9,
296.44, 296.7, NA), Axis_I_Primary_Dx = c("SCHIZ UNDIFF", "SCHIZ UNDIFF",
"SCHIZ UNDIFF", "BP I", "BP I", "CONTROL"), PMI = c(34L, 43L,
28L, 19L, 18L, 28L), Brain_PH = c(6.18, 6.63, 6.73, 5.87, 6.5,
6.59), Left_Brain = c("Fixed", "Frozen", "Frozen", "Fixed", "Frozen",
"Fixed"), Suicide_Status = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"
), Psychotic_Feature = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown",
"No"), Rate_Of_Death = c("Possible anoxia at death (e.g., CO poisoning or pneumonia)",
"Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden", "Sudden"), Exacerbation = c("No evidence of exacerbation",
"No evidence of exacerbation", "No evidence of exacerbation",
"Definite", "No evidence of exacerbation", "Unknown"), Smoking_At_TOD = c("Yes",
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Unknown"), Lifetime_Alcohol_Use = c("Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Little or none (less than 1 drink/day)",
"Social (1?2 drinks/day)", "Moderate drinking in present (same as above, for recent period)"
), Lifetime_Drug_Use = c("Moderate drug use in present", "Social",
"Heavy drug use in present", "Little or none", "Moderate drug use in present",
"Little or none"), Lifetime_Antipsychotics = c(75000L, 130000L,
2500L, 4000L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The 2nd df was not posted as a data.frame, it's the concatenation of two vectors, much better would be `dput(ann[c("Database_ID", "Profile")])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a vector of wanted profiles, select from data set `d` the columns to be in the final result, and `inner_join` with the filtered data set `ann`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

wanted_profiles <- c("BP", "Unaffected control")

pheno <- d %>%
  select(FID, IID) %>%
  inner_join(ann %>% filter(Profile %in% wanted_profiles), by=c("FID"="Database_ID")) %>%
  rename(Phenotype = Profile)

head(pheno)
#>    FID IID          Phenotype
#> 1 AC13   1                 BP
#> 2 AC14   1                 BP
#> 3 AC15   1 Unaffected control
#> 4 AC18   1                 BP
#> 5 AC19   1 Unaffected control
#> 6  AC1   1                 BP
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

To keep only `ann` columns `Database_ID` and  `Profile`, run

```
d %>%
  select(FID, IID) %>%
  inner_join(ann %>% 
               select(Database_ID, Profile) %>%
               filter(Profile %in% wanted_profiles), 
             by=c("FID"="Database_ID")) %>%
  rename(Phenotype = Profile)
```

An equivalent instruction is

```
inner_join(
  d %>% select(FID, IID),
  ann %>% select(Database_ID, Profile) %>% filter(Profile %in% wanted_profiles), 
  by = c("FID" = "Database_ID")
) %>%
  rename(Phenotype = Profile)
```

Comment: When I used your code `pheno <- d %>% select(FID, IID) %>% inner_join(ann %>% filter(Profile %in% c("BP", "Unaffected control")), by=c("FID"="Database_ID")) %>% rename(Phenotype=Profile)`, I only merge the two files for BP and unaffected control. My `pheno` dataframe contains all the `ann` columns that I don't need.

Comment: @melolili I don't understand, are you saying that `ann` has more columns? If so, before `filter` pipe `ann` to `select(Database_ID, Profile)`.

Comment: Yes, there are more columns in `ann`. I've added it to my question.

Comment: `> pheno <- d %>% select(FID, IID) %>% inner_join(ann|select("Database_ID", "Profile") %>% filter(Profile %in% c("BP", "U
naffected control")), by=c("FID"="Database_ID")) %>% rename(Phenotype=Profile)` raised an error: 
`Error in UseMethod("select") :
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: @melolili See the edit. You were selecting character variables between quotes, not columns.

Comment: oops I posted the answer before I saw yours